# How to add an action/event to radSwitch [codenameone] java

Tags: java, codenameone

The idea is triggering an accito everytime that a Switch change from OFF/OM or viceversa. I added a bind-action but it does not work.

```
<radSwitch height="0.7rem"
    bind-hidden="java:${Thing.additionalType}.bool" rad-transition="hidden 0.1s"
    tag="Person.sponsor">
    <bind-action category="PREFERREDSW"/>
</radSwitch>
```

Thank you in advance (:

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? 
See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

only worked for Button and MultiButton in CodeRAD < 2.0.5.  I've just released 2.0.5 which adds support for other components.  It should be available in maven central soon.

You just need to update the CodeRad version in your pom.xml and common/pom.xml dependencies.  You'll need to update two dependencies.

In the pom.xml file, look for

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.codenameone</groupId>
        <artifactId>coderad-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In the common/pom.xml file, look for

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.codenameone</groupId>
        <artifactId>coderad-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Once you've done this, you should either do a clean build of your project, or just make some changes in your view template to ensure that the view class gets regenerated by the annotation processor.